# Gaps in proofs of Ramanujan's identities

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification

EDIT1:

I understand that there are gaps between full proofs and verification of correct end results obtained by Srinivasa Ramanujan.. lets call this *shortcut,* for lack of a better appellation.

Among  Ramanujan’s implied shortcuts adopted without formal proof, are there among them some results

1. that have never been attempted for proof  completion/filling?
2. that were attempted analytically but not yet filled in ?
3. that were coded with intermediate steps consequently filled up with help of a computer software when they could not be brought to a linked analytical /logical conclusion?

Thanks  for the references.

Comment: Thanks to the work of Bruce C. Berndt and his collaborators, nearly all the formulas of Ramanujan in his notebooks have been analyzed in detail and proved or disproved or corrected. However there remains the mystery about Ramanujan's methods because many proofs are mere verifications.

Comment: Regarding proofs by computer, most of his difficult results have been verified using math software like maple, macsyma, Mathematica.

Comment: So that when you when you type in the statement and enter, it returns "True"? That would resound as the most modern wondrous machine experience.

Comment: OK, here is an analogy: suppose it has been proved using number theory that primes greater than $10^{100}$ have a certain property. Using computers one verifies that primes below $10^{100}$ also have that property. So it is proved with help of computers that all the primes have that property. Many of Ramanujan's results have been verified in this manner. No one knows how Ramanujan derived them. My guess is that he got those by very smart algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Also there was lot of labour involved as Ramanujan did all this algebra almost 24x7

Comment: Thanks@Paramanand Singhji, Your observation... [Ramanujan  possessed far more efficient techniques based on elementary algebra and calculus compared to modern techniques based on complex analysis, modular forms and algebraic number theory. His being a noob in complex analysis was a boon for him.] will fill many hearts that choose mathematics as a means of self-realization.

Comment: Well, I also believe the modern development of ideas discovered by Ramanujan is not exactly in line with what Ramanujan did. Instead of simplicity they have chosen more and more abstraction, theories and made such deeply interesting math widely inaccessible. A similar development in modern software goes by the name of "architectural astronauts" (coined by Joel Spolsky co-founder of stack exchange).

Comment: See the article by Joel Spolsky https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/04/21/dont-let-architecture-astronauts-scare-you/

Comment: Content-rich work must be encouraged and held high. Instead the shining formats glorify new presentations, ironically overshadowing  the very content that makes formatted structures possible.